# multiple arguments to \titleformat?

Tags: titlesec

I use the `titlesec` package with the `\titleformat` command to create fancy a `\part` style in my document. I do however need to pass an additional argument for the background image. As of now, it is specified as `backgroundimage`, and will be the same for all `\part`'s in the document. But I would like to send it as an argument like this: `\part{This is a part}{background}`

It seems it is not possible to add extra arguments with the \titleformat command. Can anyone help me to find another way to do this?

This is what I have now:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}

\titleformat{\part}
  {\normalfont\huge\filleft}
  {}
  {20pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[inner sep=0pt] (background) at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{backgroundimage}}; % bg-image
  \node[ % top block
      fill=blue,
      opacity=0.8,
      text width=2\paperwidth,
      rounded corners=0cm,
      text depth=18cm,
      anchor=center,
      inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north east) (parttop)
    {\thepart};% part number
  \node[
      anchor=south east,
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt] (partnum) at ([yshift=60pt, xshift=-20pt]parttop.south)
    {\thepart};
  \node[ % name
      anchor=south east,
      color=white,
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt] at ([yshift=30pt, xshift=-20pt]parttop.south) 
  {\parbox{1.7\textwidth}{\raggedleft#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\begin{document}


\part{This is a part}
bla bla bla

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a separate macro to store the background, then patch `part` to set this macro before printing the part:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\partbackground{}
\titleformat{\part}
  {\normalfont\huge\filleft}
  {}
  {20pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \node[inner sep=0pt] (background) at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\partbackground}}; % bg-image
  \node[ % top block
      fill=blue,
      opacity=0.8,
      text width=2\paperwidth,
      rounded corners=0cm,
      text depth=18cm,
      anchor=center,
      inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north east) (parttop)
    {\thepart};% part number
  \node[
      anchor=south east,
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt] (partnum) at ([yshift=60pt, xshift=-20pt]parttop.south)
    {\thepart};
  \node[ % name
      anchor=south east,
      color=white,
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt] at ([yshift=30pt, xshift=-20pt]parttop.south) 
  {\parbox{1.7\textwidth}{\raggedleft#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
  }
\let\origpart\part
\renewcommand\part[2]{\edef\partbackground{#2}\origpart{#1}}
\begin{document}


\part{This is a part}{some_bg.png}
bla bla bla

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd avoid overloading `\part`; also I find it better to not fill the last argument to `\titleformat` with long code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tikz}

\titleformat{\part}
  {\normalfont\huge\filleft}
  {}
  {20pt}
  {\makepartbackground}

\newcommand{\makepartbackground}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \if\relax\currentpartbackgroundimage\relax
    \else
      \node[inner sep=0pt] (background) at (current page.center) {%
        \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\currentpartbackgroundimage}%
      }; % bg-image
    \fi
  \node[ % top block
      fill=blue,
      opacity=0.8,
      text width=2\paperwidth,
      rounded corners=0cm,
      text depth=18cm,
      anchor=center,
      inner sep=0pt] at (current page.north east) (parttop)
    {\thepart};% part number
  \node[
      anchor=south east,
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt] (partnum) at ([yshift=60pt, xshift=-20pt]parttop.south)
    {\thepart};
  \node[ % name
      anchor=south east,
      color=white,
      inner sep=0pt,
      outer sep=0pt] at ([yshift=30pt, xshift=-20pt]parttop.south) 
  {\parbox{1.7\textwidth}{\raggedleft#1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand{\partbackground}[1]{\gdef\currentpartbackgroundimage{#1}}
\newcommand{\nopartbackground}{\gdef\currentpartbackgroundimage{}}
\nopartbackground

\begin{document}

\part{No background}

\partbackground{example-image}
\part{This is a part}

\end{document}
```

The chosen background image will be used until reset by `\nobackground` or by another `\partbackground` command (to be used before the corresponding `\part`).

[image]